# Website for admission results?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

Is there any website/forum where people post their application results? For instance a website where people write the name of university they applied for, their GPAs, their GRE/TOEFL scores, their subject, ... and the result of admission? I'm just eager to see some admission results from top US universities specially in Statistics and/or Computer Science.

Comment: There used to be a great list of results on physicsgre.com, but it's no longer available. The forums sections is still up, though. Sadly, this has to do with Physics and not Computer Science or Statistics, but it's probably the best "results forum" I've come across: http://www.physicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5572

Comment: Gradcafe.com has many of these aspects.

Comment: @RoboKaren It's actually thegradcafe.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, [thegradcafe.com](http://thegradcafe.com/) is the most used site for posting results. It seems that applicants from almost every discipline use their [results tracker](http://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/). However, it isn't very comprehensive when it comes to stats, and many people choose to omit the limited information that it can track.

Their forums are sometimes frequented as well depending on the discipline, while some disciplines have other common discussion sites. As far as I remember, the [statistics forum](http://forum.thegradcafe.com/forum/48-mathematics-and-statistics/) at gradcafe was fairly active during the admissions season. I know that a lot of math grad admissions discussion goes on at [mathematicsgre.com](http://www.mathematicsgre.com/), while most economics applicants gather at [urch.com](http://www.urch.com/forums/phd-economics/). I'm betting that almost every discipline has some kind of forum or discussion site that people congregate at, but I am not as familiar with other fields.

If you're looking for in-depth profiles, these forums are often the best places to look. The sample size isn't very high, but most of the time they have some kind of "Profiles and Results" thread each year that people post in (e.g. [stats](http://forum.thegradcafe.com/topic/60631-2015-applicant-profiles-admission-results-biostatisticsstatistics/), [econ](http://www.urch.com/forums/phd-economics/155010-profiles-results-2015-a.html)).

Answer (score 2):

thegradcafe.com is a popular website that, as far as I am aware, is the only site that really covers most of what you're asking for. If you search for some key words you can get a spread of a single program or university, and you can see what kinds of students are getting in or rejected.

However, people don't always state all of their information... I have seen many people who just say they "got in" or didn't. So it isn't always the most helpful source for anything but statistics, which you want, but that can be moot if only four or five students have said anything about the particular program. This happens a lot. It isn't the best spread. I also can't imagine there isn't lying going on.

One lesson to take away from that website is that there's an amazingly broad set of students both getting in and being rejected by all sorts of universities... I believe that it's a much more complex process than in undergraduate institutions. Perhaps don't be so concerned about where you match up against a couple of people there. Ask your advisors, perhaps, where you may stand, or better yet, be in touch with professors at your chosen institution!

Comment: Warning to applicants: while useful in many ways, I was eventually refreshing grad cafe every fifteen seconds